# Does Rejecting an offer of a peace treaty influence warmongering penalties?

Tags: civilization-6

An AI nation starts a surprise war against me, and later asks for a peace treaty.

Does rejecting such an offer influence warmongering penalties or upset other AI players?

Comment: I don't think it does, though being at war gives war weariness after a bit, and the terms of accepting peace do influence relationships with other civs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rejecting peace offers does not influence warmonger penalties.

Warmongering penalties are primarily applied when the war is initially declared. That's why the AI tends to mass-denounce the aggressor the next turn. A player can receive additional warmonger penalties for razing cities, and in some cases for capturing cities.

Comment: The in-game text also mentions that keeping captured cities at the end of the war can add to your warmonger penalty as well.

Comment: I have noticed since asking the question that peace treaty offers can include offering to "cede" cities you've captured. I guess that means no, or reduced warmongering penalties if you accept. (And there are the in-game notices saying that, for example, returning city-states (at least) to the original founder "severely" decreases warmongering penalties. So, accepting a peace treaty offer in and of itself may not influence it, but can be related in certain situations.

Comment: @JimReynolds Yeah, if you cede the city you loose the warmonger penalty for taking the city (but not for declaring the original war).

Comment: I had forgotten that a key part of my question involves its first clause: Assuming an AI declares war on me! It shouldn't be warmongerish to be on the barrel end of a DOW. But do warmongering penalties occur if the aggressor subsequently offers peace and I reject it, and/or if I take and keep lots of cities while "defending" myself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing right now as Saladin and was attacked by Amanitore and Mvemba a Nzinga in a formal war. I defeated Amanitore's army in the field (Mvemba never showed up) and I am now rolling through Nubia's territory taking her cities and ignoring her repeated requests for peace. After two cities, Trajan congratulated my on the size of my empire, but after three he denounced me as a warmonger.

So I would say, yes. Refusing peace treaties, or capturing cities after ignoring an opportunity for peace will upset third-party leaders.